# Reading xml and locating the rows in tiff file

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, deep-learning, computer-vision, tiff

I have RDCL 2015 dataset containing the ground truth and sample images with tiff extension. I want to take in ground truth from the xml files and images from the tiff.

The objective is to read the XML and  locate the rows within the .tiff files

I am new to this field so I don't have any idea how it's done any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: nope nothing yet

Comment: thinking of parsing it through xml tree.